# The page you are looking for might have been removed had its name changed or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: asp.net

How would i fix this error.After publishing an asp.net site when i try to view page i get  this error "The page you are looking for might have been removed had its name changed or is temporarily unavailable". Everything worked fine until i enabled windows authentication in the web.config.

I'm i doing anything wrong? Please help...

My web.config looks like this

```
    <system.web>

        <httpModules>     
          <add name="WindowsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsAuthenticationModule" />     
          <add name="AnonymousIdentification" type="System.Web.Security.AnonymousIdentificationModule" />      
        </httpModules>

        <identity impersonate="true"/>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
       <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>
      <!--<authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
      </authentication>-->
      <authentication mode="Windows">      
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
          <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
      <membership>
       <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
       </providers>
      </membership>
      <profile>
       <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
       </providers>
      </profile>
      <roleManager enabled="false">
       <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
       </providers>
      </roleManager>
      <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to control panel> Internet Opetions> Advance Tab> click "restore advance settings"> click "reset"> then a dialog box will open> click delete personal settings and wait, let computer to complete the process and then click cloes.
Note: during this process your browser should be tuned off.

100% working for me.

Regards,

Muhammad Atique Ashrafi

Comment: This does not seem to address the question being asked. (Where user looses access when the windows authentication is turned on).

Answer (score 0):

debug your global asax.  Are you using MVC ? Propabely, when you request a web-page it detects that you are not authenticated, and reroutes you the the login page. If there is no login page, it will say: page does not exist.

Check if the the url with your login page exists.

This can be done by checking the requests in firebug, or in your global asax.

Grtz